# Postgres COPY into hstore field with double quote in value

Tags: sql, postgresql, escaping, postgis, hstore

I have been trying for hours to populate a Postgres 12 database from a CSV file using the `COPY` command. The table in question has an `hstore` field and one of the key-value-pairs has a double quote `"` in the value.

The Postgres database is created like this

```
CREATE TABLE test ( 
    title VARCHAR(20),
    tags hstore
);
```

The CSV file uses `tabs` as delimiters and looks like this

```
My Title | name=>"""Paul "Butch" Newman""", job=>actor
```

The name value needs to be double quoted and escaped because it contains spaces.

`|` *represents one tab character.*

My import statement looks like this:

```
COPY test (title, tags) 
FROM '/var/lib/postgresql/data/test.csv'
DELIMITER E'\t' CSV ENCODING 'UTF8';
```

The database is populated as expected, but when I query it with

`SELECT tags->'name' as name FROM test;`

pgAdmin 4 returns

`Paul Butch Newman`

instead of

`Paul "Butch" Newman`

**My question is how to get the double quotes into the actual hstore value?**

I found many answers regarding double quotes for the import into text fields. But here the import is into an `hstore` field and the value needs to be double quoted here as it contains spaces.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just played with this locally.

I assume that you have control over the format of your input file.

The problem is that the CSV format converts `""` found within elements enclosed enclosed in double-quotes to `"` when passing them up.

This worked for me to get the result you want:

```
My Title | name=>"""Paul \""Butch\"" Newman""", job=>actor
```

Once the CSV handler is done with its escaping by turning doubled double-quotes to single quotes, it passes `name=>"Paul \"Butch\" Newman", job=>actor` to the `insert`, which is how you would write it as a literal in psql or PgAdmin.

```
select tags->'name' as name
  from test_hstor;

        name         
---------------------
 Paul "Butch" Newman
(1 row)
```

Out of curiosity, I checked on importing it as text instead of csv, and the input record has to contain `name=>"Paul \\"Butch\\" Newman", job=>actor` to work right.

Comment: Excellent, that works great. Thank you! Another idea that just came was to replace the quotes with unicode literals, but I have not tried that yet.